# what is the asp:textbox.MaxLength default value

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox, default-value, maxlength

My question is that suppose i have an asp:textbox and i do not specify MaxLength property of it then what will be the default length will  it be unlimited or there is some limit on the number of characters. this question may seem pretty easy to answer fro someone but i am not clear at it

thank you in advance

Comment: why some one is angry with this question. bother about putting some comments how should i improve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value is 0 means no limit. For reference visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx) link

Comment: thanks for the answer with a reference to it :) it helped me.now its clear

Comment: @Devjosh we all are here to help each other achieving our goals:)

Answer (score 2):

(code spied by reflector ...)

```
[DefaultValue(0), Themeable(false), WebSysDescription("TextBox_MaxLength"), WebCategory("Behavior")]
public virtual int MaxLength
{
    get
    {
        object obj2 = this.ViewState["MaxLength"];
        if (obj2 != null)
        {
            return (int) obj2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        }
        this.ViewState["MaxLength"] = value;
    }
}
```

this property will be used by following code:

```
int maxLength = this.MaxLength;
if (maxLength > 0)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Maxlength, maxLength.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
}
maxLength = this.Columns;
if (maxLength > 0)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Size, maxLength.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of the text that can be entered in the control is limited only by `available memory`, if you not specify the `MaxLength` explicitly

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:TextBox />` is mapped to a HTML `<input type="text" />` control.

The default maxlength for an HTML-`<input type="text" />` control is according to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)   524288. ( = 512 x 1024 chars)

`<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" />` is mapped to a HTML `<textarea />`.
The default-maxlength is unlimited. The max length of the text is limited by the method used to send data to the server ("GET" or "POST") and the servers ability to receive huge data. (ASP.NET web.config `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx kb" />`)